# How to export output as enviromental variable permanently via cronjob?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, cron

Whenever I run this in terminal:

```
export PRIVATEIP=`ip address show | awk '{print $2}' | grep -oE "\b([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\b" | grep "10.*"`
```

It exports the value from the command

```
ip address show | awk '{print $2}' | grep -oE "\b([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\b" | grep "10.*"
```

So when I call $PRIVATEIP in a script, the IP number will be fetched.

Now I would like to run this command as a cronjob, because the IP changes regularly. This export needs to be available permanently for everyone/everywhere who runs $PRIVATEIP.

This is what I have in my crontab:

```
* * * * * /bin/bash /home/scriptfolder/script.sh
```

This is what script.sh look like:

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/bin:/home/scriptfolder
export PRIVATEIP=`ip address show | awk '{print $2}' | grep -oE "\b([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\b" | grep "10.*"`
```

Can anyone tell me WHY its not working as I want? Whenever I run $PRIVATEIP in terminal after activating this cronjob it obviously does not export (or show*) the current ip.

Should it be inserted/updated in `~/.bashrc`? If yes, wont there be duplicate PRIVATEIP-lines then?

Hope you understand my shitty English and messy text. Im a newbie when it comes to Linux so all help is welcome.

Comment: The environment is only inherited by child processes. Exporting in a cron job doesn't have any effect on other processes that aren't descendants of that cron job.,

Comment: A better solution would be to write it to a file in the cronjob, and than use `$(<filename)` in the scripts.

Comment: Haha it sounds sooo easy when you say it =D I think I understood. But I am not sure if the script/software I will be running supports $(<filename). I know for sure that it supports $PRIVATEIP. Or is this some "universal OS language" that will be recognized?

Comment: More universal is `$(cat filename)`

Comment: `--p2p-local-ip $(cat /home/scriptfolder/privateip.txt) --second-command X --third-command Y`
Whats wrong =D? ......... This is a ExecStart=/ variable for a systemd-file. Any idea why it wont read the content of privateip.txt?

Comment: Nothing wrong if that's in a shell script. Are you getting an error?

Comment: So it should work just like that if in the service-file ExecStart?
`--p2p-local-ip $(cat /home/scriptfolder/privateip.txt) --second-command X --third-command Y`

Comment: No, `systemd` commands are not executed by the shell. The [documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html) says **This syntax is inspired by shell syntax, but only the meta-characters and expansions described in the following paragraphs are understood**. Command substitution is not supported.

Comment: But you could put it in a shell script, and then use `execStart` to run the script.

Comment: Note also that doing the `export` in your own shell also wouldn't affect the environment of `systemd`. It gets its environment when the system boots.

Comment: Haha this is way too complicated for me :D If you by any chance can see a simple solution to [https://old.reddit.com/r/WireGuard/comments/ls64nk/ping_googlecom_if_fail_reconnect_wireguard_to_the/?](https://old.reddit.com/r/WireGuard/comments/ls64nk/ping_googlecom_if_fail_reconnect_wireguard_to_the/) which is really my main problem - this was just a workaround... Feel free and I will send you $30.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check your `PATH`?
You are calling the programs `ip`, `awk` and `grep`.
Bash will look at the path for finding the location of the programs, so it will only look in `/usr/bin` and `/home/scriptfolder`.
Where are they?

```
command -v ip
command -v awk
command -v grep
# when command -v grep shows an alias, try
which grep
```

Change your `PATH` to match the locations of the programs.

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/home/scriptfolder
```

A harder way is calling all programs with a full path:

```
export PRIVATEIP=$(/sbin/ip address show |
   /usr/bin/awk '{print $2}' | 
   /bin/grep -oE "\b([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\b" |
   grep "10.*")
```

Now `PRIVATEIP` is known in `/home/scriptfolder/script.sh` (and forgotten when the script is finished).